# Quartz Job not running when a class calls another class

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

So, I'm very new to Quartz. And I have this application, where I'm picking up data from a DB, writing it into an Excel sheet and sending a mail notification. This has to be done weekly. For testing, I have set my Trigger to repeat every 5 mins for now. So, here's my JobListener:

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContext) {
    Scheduler scheduler;
    try {
        System.out.println("Context Initialized");
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(ScheduledJob.class).withIdentity("schduledJob", "Group").build();
        System.out.println("Job Build");
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("simpleTrigger", "group")
                .withSchedule(
                    SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                    .withIntervalInSeconds(300).repeatForever())
                .build();
        System.out.println("Trigger");
        scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        System.out.println("Before Scheduler Start");
        scheduler.start();
        System.out.println("After Scheduler Start");
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        System.out.println("Job Scheduled");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.getStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here's my Job class:

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) {
    try {
        DataFromDB getData = new DataFromDB();
        System.out.println("Job Started");
        getData.getDataFromDB();
        System.out.println("Job End");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I have two different classes for writing this to excel and sending the email. These methods are called somewhere inside the getDataFromDB() method. Now, when I run my application, it gives no error, no exception, just stops at the point where I'm creating the objects to call the other two methods from the getDataFromDB() method. If I remove those lines, i.e. creating objects and calling those methods, it runs till the end. If I remove it and place it somewhere furher down, it again runs uptill that point and then stops. I have no clue what is happening or why. Thanx in advance for helping me.

Comment: How did you verify that the call stops at specific line? If you are using debugger to verify that, make sure your running the latest code.

Comment: Multiple syso statements. The lines just before object initialization is printed and nothing after that gets executed.

Comment: Can u paste the getDataFromDB() method?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. Some specific confidential information is there in the code. But, trust me, I've tried creating the object for the other class as the first statement of this class, kept it in the middle, everytime the result is the same. The code stops when I call the export to excel method. If required, I can paste the method where I'm writing the data to Excel. Will that help?

Answer (score 0):

I always use something like this:

```
 Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DBConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection(dataSourceName);

            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(querySql);
            stmt.setString(1, sParameter);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
          //whatever you need
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to execute DB connection action.", e);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
                conn = null;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to close DB connection.", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

I can put it into a single class and I have no problem.
Of course, you must define de datasource in Quartz.properties.
Hope this helps!